# a complete reference for workout and exercises tips with animated pictures

Tags: exercise, workout

I'm looking for a free well-documented and of course a complete reference for learning workout and fitness exercises with animated pictures (.GIF format).

while googleing I found http://www.fitnessbliss.com/en/exercises but these are complete.

I want some thing which can be downloaded in my phone, should compact animated files.

any answer appreciated.

Comment: You want exrx.net

Comment: EXRX is The Site, period. But there are excellent video descriptions for each exercise in www.bodybuilding.com, if you you are able to ignore the rest of the contents of the site (posts with brainwashing about supplements, and crazy high-volume routines designed to exhaust you and make you feel the need for supplements).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want [exrx.net](http://www.exrx.net). For example, [this exercise](http://www.exrx.net/WeightExercises/GluteusMaximus/BBDeadlift.html), this [training advice](http://www.exrx.net/WeightTraining/Mistakes.html), and this [directory of exercises](http://www.exrx.net/Lists/Directory.html).

Comment: these are greate, BUT if there were some higher-quality GIFs it would be better. again thanks

Comment: impersonaltrainers.wordpress.com & blisslogik.com are some kinda good resources, for the ones need it.